# How to create many hash references with identical data?

Tags: perl

I am trying to create many hash references with identical contents. Using the `x` operator gives copies of the same reference. How can I get different references?

I need different references so that I can later update them independently of others.

My Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use feature qw(say);
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my %UNIT_COUNT = (
    numsys   => 6,
    alg      => 20,
    geo      => 15,
    cogeo    => 6,
    trig     => 12,
    mensur   => 10,
    statprob => 11
);

my $out = [
       map {
            ( { unit => $_, weight => 1 } ) x
              ( $UNIT_COUNT{$_} )
        } keys %UNIT_COUNT
    ];

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($out);
```

Comment: Not sure whether I got this -- what should be the content of those many hashrefs? Do you want each to have a copy of a given hash (`%UNIT_COUNT` here) or are you trying to build different data from it?

Comment: @zdim I want something to replace the part `{ unit => $_, weight => 1 } ) x ( $UNIT_COUNT{$_} )` which produces different hashrefs. I want to make  a list with `$UNIT_COUNT{$_}` hashrefs for each key `$_` in `%UNIT_COUNT`. The content of hashrefs depends on the key but is otherwise identical. The answer by @toolic does what I want. I wonder if there is a more consise/clear way to achieve this.

Comment: Oh, OK.  I (honestly :) don't understand what you mean, nor do I understand reasoning for toolic's output (I do understand the code of course), but it clearly isn't what I thought.  Thank you for clarifying, removing my mis-answer.

Comment: @zdim you can think about it like converting a discrete frequency distribution into raw data observations in such a way that the observations can be later modified independently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This uses another `map` instead of the `x` operator, but it does give you copies:

```
my $out = [
    map {
        my $k = $_;
        map { { unit => $k, weight => 1 } } 1 .. $UNIT_COUNT{$_}
    } keys %UNIT_COUNT
];
```

Partial output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'unit' => 'mensur',
            'weight' => 1
          },
          {
            'weight' => 1,
            'unit' => 'mensur'
          },
          {
            'unit' => 'mensur',
            'weight' => 1
          },
          {
            'unit' => 'mensur',
            'weight' => 1
          },
```